# Signed URl for Amazon

Tags: amazone-rest-api-version

I need to create a signed URL for amazon for a file in a my AWS bucket. This URL has to get expired after a given period of time.
i am getting stuck in creating the signature for url

Comment: Are you trying to generate this signed request inside of Salesforce with Apex?

Comment: Yes, i am creating it in apex